# Why $\Bbb{R}$ being archimedean implies that $A=\{m\inℤ, \frac{m}{p}\ge b\}$ is a non-empty set of integers?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

There is this statement in my book:

"Be $A=\{m\inℤ, \frac{m}{p}\ge b\}$. As $\Bbb{R}$ is archimedean, A is a non-empty set of integers."

$p$ is an integer number and $b$ is a real number.

I understood that as $\Bbb{R}$ is archimedean, than $\Bbb{N}\subset\Bbb{R}$ isn't upper bounded, since $\Bbb{N}\subset A$, we have that $A$ isn't upper bounded too. So $A$ is a non-empty set of integers.

Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: You're looking for integers $m$ such that $m\geq bp$, but how do you know that there even exist such integers? That's exactly what the Archimedean property gives you

Comment: Could you show what Archimedean property shows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $A$ is not empty, because, by the Archimedean property of $\mathbf R$, given $\frac1 p$ and $b$, there exists  a natural number $m$ such that
$$m\cdot \frac 1p>b.$$

Comment: Should it not be $>$ instead of $\ge$ ?

Comment: This depends on formulation. Anyway, if a multiple of $\frac1p$ is equal to $b$, the next multiple is greater.

Comment: Ok. I've just found it strange because in my book this inequation is with $>$.